# UITableView Custom cell changing values iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, custom-cell

I am facing an issue in custom cell, while scrolling up and down the values in the cell changing. I have added 2 buttons in the last section. Please check the below code. Any help, much appreciated. Thanks a ton.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    DrinkCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {

        cell = [[DrinkCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == [tableView numberOfSections] - 1)
    {
        cell.tileImage.hidden = YES;
        cell.pizzaTopins.hidden = YES;
        // cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {

            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, cell.bounds.size.width);
            UILabel *calorieLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2-30/2, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
            calorieLabel.text = @"1000 Calories | 700 grams of fat";
            cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColorApp;

            [cell addSubview:calorieLabel];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

            cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColorApp;
            NSLog(@"cell width : %f",cell.contentView.frame.size.width);

            UIView *quantityView = [[UIView alloc]init];
            quantityView.frame = CGRectMake(25 ,cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2-50/2, cell.contentView.frame.size.width-55, 50);
            quantityView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor whiteColor];
            quantityView.clipsToBounds      = YES;
            quantityView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            quantityView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;

            UIButton *decreaseButton  = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, quantityView.frame.size.height/2-35/2, 35, 35)];
            [decreaseButton setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [quantityView addSubview:decreaseButton];
            [decreaseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(decreaseQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [decreaseButton setTitleColor:quantityButtonColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [decreaseButton setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            decreaseButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
            decreaseButton.layer.cornerRadius = 17.5f;
            decreaseButton.layer.borderColor = quantityButtonColor.CGColor;
            decreaseButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
            int i =0;
            quantityLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(quantityView.frame.size.width/2-30/2, quantityView.frame.size.height/2-30/2, 30, 30)];
            quantityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
            [quantityLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
            quantityLabel.textColor = quantityButtonColor;
            [quantityView addSubview:quantityLabel];


            UIButton *increaseButton  = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(quantityView.frame.size.width-45, quantityView.frame.size.height/2-35/2, 35, 35)];

            [increaseButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [increaseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [quantityView addSubview:increaseButton];
            increaseButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [increaseButton setTitleColor:quantityButtonColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            increaseButton.layer.cornerRadius = 17.5f;
            increaseButton.layer.borderColor = quantityButtonColor.CGColor;
            increaseButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;

            [cell addSubview:quantityView];
            [quantityView addSubview:decreaseButton];
            [quantityView addSubview:increaseButton];
        }
        else  if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            addTocartButton  = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2 - 50/2, cell.contentView.frame.size.width-55, 50)];

            [addTocartButton setTitle:@"Add to Cart" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [addTocartButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addToCartOnCreatePizza:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            addTocartButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190.0f/255.0f green:19.0f/255.0f blue:31.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
            //   [cell.contentView addSubview:addTocartButton];
            [cell.contentView insertSubview:addTocartButton atIndex:0];
            addTocartButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
            addTocartButton.layer.cornerRadius =10.0f;

        }
    }

    cell.pizzaTopins.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190.0f/255.0f green:19.0f/255.0f blue:31.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    cell.pizzaTopins.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile44.png"];

    //  cell.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what exactly issue you are facing? not getting your question.

Comment: while scrolling, tableview looks so messy. Buttons and labels are collapsed.

Comment: There is no problem if I remove the buttons which I added in the last section. But if I add buttons, while scrolling down and going up, buttons comes in the first row.

Comment: Can you add 2 screenshots before/after scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will "reuse" previously created cells so you have to make sure to re-initialize all manually added/modified attributes including any buttons you added programatically.

Screen shots would help us properly diagnose the issue but your code is vulnerable to lingering attributes of reused cells so I would suggest starting with that.

BTW you would probably end up with simpler code if you defined multiple cell prototypes in IB and varied the cellIdentifier based on the indexPath row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already fixed by creating another customer cell in storyboard.